# How to know how many rows of code are there for a CLI shell?

Tags: bash, shell, filesystems, architecture, development

How to know how many rows of code are there for a CLI shell, not counting empty lines?

The purpose of this question is to learn how I could count the rows of code for both `sh` and `Bash` CLI shells.

Given the kernel has about 15 million rows of code, I did have a wonder on the magnitude of rows of code for these 2 programs letting me interface with the kernel.

Comment: You would have to download the source for the shell in question.  Then you could use a tool like [`cloc`](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) or similar to count the lines of code in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the latest version of **bash**, i.e. bash v4.4, the answer is 134576. The command I use is

```
find . -name '*.[ch]' | xargs grep -v '^\s*$' | wc -l
```

`find . -name '*.[ch]'` means find files that has ends with `.c` or `.h` (not counting the `.def`, `.po` files although I think it's part of source code too)

in, `grep -v '^\s*$'` (historical note, change form [\s*] to \s*),

- `-v` prints only the lines that do *not* match
- `^` means line start
- `$` means line end
- `\s` means whitespaces including space, tab, linefeed

so `grep -v '^[\s]*$'` excludes lines have only whitespaces and `wc -l` counts them.

There are many **sh** source codes, for UNIX v6 sh(https://etsh.io/history/sh.c). There are only 860 lines.

Comment: `[\s]` means one character, either `s` or backslash.  Grep does not use Perl regular expressions by default. For whitespace, use `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: @Kusalananda GNU grep recognise \s by default. Using posix standardized [[:space:]] is more robust but less convenient.

Comment: `ggrep (GNU grep) 3.1` does not recognize `\s` inside `[...]` as anything else than the characters `s` or backslash. I guess you meant `\s` rather than `[\s]`.

Comment: Amusingly, there actually are lines in that source tree that only contain backslashes, 29 of them, parts of macro definitions in `include/shmbutil.h`. And around 300 that only have whitespace. It doesn't change the final number by much though, but the pattern still doesn't do what you'd expect.

Comment: Also, for some reason which I can't understand, using `^\s*$` or `^[[:space:]]*$` as the pattern seems about 10x slower than e.g. `^ *$`.

Comment: @Kusalananda You are right. [...] is nonsense here. I update my answers.

Comment: @ilkkachu I think it's caused by implementation of regex, SPACE has only one character,while \s means a set [ \t\r\n\v\f] which has more states. You can find more in grep source dfa.c and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton

Answer (score -1):

If I've understood correctly, then your friend is the command wc.

```
# cat example
passwd

group

# wc -l example
3 example

# grep -v "^$" example | wc -l
2
```

Or only with grep:

```
# grep -c . example
2
```

If there are multiple files. As an example with the bash sourcecode.

```
# wget -c https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4.tar.gz
# tar xfvz bash-4.4.tar.gz
# grep -R -c . bash-4.4/ | awk -F : '{sum += $2} END {print sum}'
```